# How do I loop different percentages of missing values using MCAR?

Tags: r, machine-learning

Using the cleveland data from MCI data respository, I want to generate missing values on the data to apply some imputation techniques.

```
heart.ds <- read.csv(file.choose())
head(heart.ds)
attach(heart.ds)
sum(is.na(heart.ds))
str(heart.ds)

#Changing Appropriate Variables to Factors
heart.ds$sex<-as.factor(heart.ds$sex)
heart.ds$cp<-as.factor(heart.ds$cp)
heart.ds$fbs<-as.factor(heart.ds$fbs)
heart.ds$exang<-as.factor(heart.ds$exang)
heart.ds$restecg<-as.factor(heart.ds$restecg)
heart.ds$slope<-as.factor(heart.ds$slope)
heart.ds$thal<-as.factor(heart.ds$thal)
heart.ds$target<-as.factor(heart.ds$target)
str(heart.ds)
```

Now i want to generate missing values using the MCAR mechanism. Below is the loop code;

```
p = c(0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1)

hd_mcar = rep(0, length(heart.ds)) #to generate empty bins of 10 different percentages of missingness using the MCAR package

for(i in 1:length(p)){
  hd_mcar[i] <- delete_MCAR(heart.ds, p[i]) #to generate 10 different percentages of missingness using the MCAR package
}
```

The problem here is that, after the above code, i dont get the data been generated in it original values like in a data frame where i will have n variables and n rows.

Below is a picture of the output i had through the above code;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj5fH.png)

But when i use only one missingness percentage i get an accurate results; below is the coe for only one missing percentage

```
#Missing Completely at Random(MCAR)
hd_mcar <- delete_MCAR(heart.ds, 0.05)
sum(is.na(hd_mcar))
```

Below is the output of the results;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hkgi.png)

Please I need help to to solve the looping problem. Thank you.

Now I want to apply the MICE and other imputations methods like HMISC, Amelia, mi, and missForest inside the loop but it is giving me an error saying "Error: Data should be a matrix or data frame"

The code below is for only MICE;

#1. Method(MICE)

```
  mice_mcar[[i]] <- mice(hd_mcar, m=ip, method = c("pmm","logreg","polyreg","pmm","pmm","logreg",
                                            "polyreg","pmm","logreg","pmm","polyreg","pmm",
                                            "polyreg","logreg"), maxit = 20)
      
  #Diagnostic check
  summary(heart.ds$age)
  mice_mcar$imp$age
  
  #Finding the means of the impuatations
  app1 <- apply(mice_mcar$imp$age, MARGIN = 2, FUN = mean)
  min1 <- abs(app1-mean(heart.ds$age))
  
  #Selecting the minimum index
  sm1 <- which(min1==min(min1))
  
  #Selecting final imputation
  final_clean_hd_mcar =mice::complete(mice_mcar,sm1)
  mice.mcar = final_clean_hd_mcar
```

How do i go about to make it fit into the loop and works perfectly?

Comment: Tip, don't use ``attach``, it's dangerous. Use ``with``, it's much safer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was this line:

```r
hd_mcar = rep(0, length(heart.ds)) #to generate empty bins of 10 different percentages of missingness using the MCAR package
```

You are creating a vector here rather than a list. You can't assign a data frame to an element of a vector without coercing it into something that is not a data frame. You want to do this:

```r
p  <- c(0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1)

hd_mcar  <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(p))

for(i in 1:length(p)){
  hd_mcar[[i]] <- delete_MCAR(heart.ds, p[i]) #to generate 10 different percentages of missingness using the MCAR package
}
```

Note that because it's a list now, `hd_mcar[[i]]` uses the `[[` rather than `[` subscript.